# Which attribute will stop users changing input data but allow jQuery to modify?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, input

I have seen people recommending

```
<input name="input" readonly="readonly">
```

and

```
<input name="input" disabled="disabled">
```

But which of these two will:

1. Stop users changing the value
2. Allow jQuery to update the value

Comment: Both can be modified by jquery but I suggest the first.

Comment: Don't forget the quote at the end of `"readonly"`.

Comment: If you don't want user input then I would not use an input, personally, otherwise `@Barmar`s answer should do.

Answer (score 3):

Use `readonly`, because `disabled` will also prevent the field from being submitted.